# "Does not make changes" or "makes no changes"

Tags: word-choice, word-order, negation, writing-style, no-not

I was thinking of using this sentence on my computer program:

> This action does not make changes on user's machine.

Just to be sure, I checked Google Translate which suggested:

> This action makes no changes on user's machine.

I suppose that both are correct and have the same meaning, but is there reason to use one instead of the other?

Comment: Related: [Rules for 'no' and 'not'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50066/rules-for-no-and-not), [About the 'no' and 'not'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9427/about-the-no-and-not)

Comment: OP's actual question is entirely a matter of stylistic choice. But including an article before *"user's machine"* is **not** a matter of choice - it must either be *"the/a/any user's machine"*. Or *"users' machines"* - both pluralised - which imho is the preferred option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of the following meaning the same thing.

> This action makes no changes on the user's machine.
>
> This action does not make changes on the user's machine.
>
> This action does not make any changes on the user's machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "makes no changes" carries a slight implication that the action could make changes (but doesn't), while "does not make changes" implies that it couldn't possibly change anything. But they're pretty interchangeable.

Comment: In "does not make changes", I see no real (unambiguous) implication of "couldn't possibly change anything".