# Should the use of apostrophes be consistent?

Tags: word-choice, differences, grammaticality, contractions, writing-style

> It is time to rock, but don't be too loud.

Is it recommended to stay consistent with the use of apostrophes? Should it instead be:

> It's time to rock, but don't be too loud.

If that is fine either way, what about using the same words with and without apostrophes such as *do not* and *don't*?

Comment: And by the way, congrats on asking the 14000th question here!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Words like *it's* and *don't* are called *contractions*.  There's no rule or reason why you should either contract all possible phrases in a sentence, or else keep them uncontracted.  In fact, I read your examples several times before I figured out the difference between them.  It's fine either way, and the same goes for *don't/do not*.

That said, there are some times when a contraction has a slightly different flavor than its uncontracted counterpart.  *Don't* is an example of this, sounding more colloquial and less stilted in informal speech than *do not*.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I thought it was a matter of style.

Comment: It *is* a matter of style.  *Don't* means the same as *do not*, but the style is different. (Or is that what you said?)

Comment: @Daniel: Okay, I'll confess too! I only upvoted your comment to thank you for the chuckle on [your recently deleted answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61326/)! Since I'm in confessional mode I should admit that since writing that last sentence I've re-read your comment in light of domino's preceding, and got another laugh! Without vocal inflection, how do we know which version he meant? *"I **had thought** it was a matter of style (thanks for straightening me out)"*, or *"I **always thought** it was a matter of style (thanks for confirming my thinking)"*. The text is *not* all!