# What is the difference between "no" and "not"?

Tags: differences, negation, no-not

What is the difference between "no" and "not"?
We know that "no" and "not" have the same meaning.
I'm studying English. I hope to get help. 
Sorry for my language.

Comment: General reference. For most purposes, "no" means "not any", where "not" is the general-purpose negator.

Comment: Related: [“Does not make changes” or “makes no changes”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61326/does-not-make-changes-or-makes-no-changes) and tons of others. Just search the site.

Answer (score 7):

NO negates the noun while NOT negates the verb.

eg:

- There are NO people here. (noun being negated: people)
- The people are NOT present. (verb being negated: to be (ARE NOT))

Comment: Nice and concise.

Answer (score 1):

*No* expresses a general negative, such as when disagreeing, or indicates an absence of any of a particular noun.

> No, I do not like coffee.
>
> There was no coffee in his house.

(According to wikipedia): *Not* is the declarative form of no.

I'm pretty sure it classifies as an adverb, and negates the action of the verb in the emphatic form (do + verb).

> I did not go to school today.
>
> The train did not arrive.