# When to use 'no good'; when to use 'not good'?

Tags: differences, word-usage, negation, no-not

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “no” and “not”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64369/what-is-the-difference-between-no-and-not)

there is a question always confusing me. Is it 'no good' or 'not good'? How do I use them? I guess they are different, but I never know what is the difference! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add some example sentences to provide context.  As is, your question can't properly be answered.  Oh, when you edit your question, remove the "Thank you in advance!" part.

Comment: Possible dupplicate of [What is the difference between "no" and "not"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64369/18425)

Answer (score 2):

From OED (**good**):

> colloq. ***to be any, some, no good***: to be any, some, no use. Also of persons, ***to be no good*** = 'to be a bad lot', to be worthless. Also of things ***a bit of no good***, quite a lot of harm.

**No good** functions as both an attributive adjective (e.g., ***a no-good dirty dog***) and noun (e.g., ***what a no good***)

On the other hand, saying that something is ***not good*** is just indicating that the adjective 'good' does not apply to it. In many instances, **no good** and **not good** can both be used. **No good** is certainly the more informal alternative.

Answer (score -1):

The only difference I can immediately think of is:

'No good' implies *doing* something, so an idea is 'no good', a lamp is 'no good' if it doesn't light and software is 'no good' if it doesn't work.

'Not good' seems more of a property of the substance, so milk that has gone bad is 'not good'

Comment: -1: I would have liked to see some references. It seems like this is just a hunch.